# Do we need the [natural-language] tag, separate from [nlp]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Do we need the [natural-language](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-language) tag? I see it's pretty much used as a synonym for [nlp](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nlp).

Comment: Hi @Franck, do you want to accept one of the answers? The tags have been made synonyms now.

Comment: @amoeba Sure, I am not a huge fan of "natural-language" though, too bad "natural-language-processing" isn't a valid tag.

Comment: It could technically be a valid tag, but there is always a constraint to try to make tags as short as possible...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've mapped `nlp` to `natural-language`.

Comment: Hmm, just to double-check: I don't see it appearing here http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms. Does it take some time to get running, or were you only *going* to map it but have not yet?

Comment: @amoeba: I think I thought I'd done it. Anyway I did it (again?) just now, & it's appeared.

Answer (score 9):

As there are two tags, namely [nlp](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nlp) and [natural-language](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-language), I think the [nlp](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nlp) tag can be merged in with the [natural-language](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-language) tag.

**Update:** As @amoeba has clearly pointed out, [nlp](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nlp) would be confusing as it can be both natural language processing and neuro-linguistic programming, so [natural-language](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-language) should be an apt tag.

Comment: I would suggest to have [natural-language] as the master tag because when I see "NLP", the first thing that comes to mind is the so called "neuro-linguistic programming", and it's confusing.

Comment: Ahh, totally forgot about that. Seems like natural-language seems like the better bet.  Edited the answer.

Comment: NLP for me is "non-linear programming".

Comment: @Weiwei I find non-linear optimization clearer :)